# The equation of the roots

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

If a, b and c are the roots of the equation $9x^3 — 7x + 6 = 0$, then the equation whose roots are $3a + 2, 3b + 2, 3c + 2$ is

Can I just replace the the $x$ with $3a + 2, 3b + 2, 3c + 2$ **???** Assuming the roots are symmetric.
If I need to prove that the roots are symmetric what is the method?

Comment: Welcome to Maths StackExchange.  I'm a little confused.  Are you supposed to prove that the format of the roots are given by $3a + 2$, $3b = 2$ and $3c + 2$?

Comment: a, b and c are the roots of the equation given. I was asked to find the equation which got the roots 3a+2,3b+2,3c+2

Comment: Then what's $x$, $y$ and $z$?

Comment: The equation which would be having the roots 3a+2, 3b+2, 3c+2 will be having x. There are no y nd z

Comment: Then why did you mention $y$ and $z$?

Comment: Sorry! i edited the question. Go through it again. I think now it will make sense.

Comment: Assume $f(z)$ has a zero at $z=a$, i.e. $f(a)=0$. What happens, when you plug in $z=3a+2$ to $f((z-2)/3)$?

Comment: In other words, if $u=3v+2$ then $v=(u-2)/3$.

Comment: $y=3x+2 \Rightarrow x=\frac{y-2}{3}$. $9x^3-7x+6=\frac{y^3-6y^2+5y+24}{3}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint…set $y=3x+2\implies x=\frac{y-2}{3}$

Now substitute this into the polynomial given to obtain the required new polynomial

Comment: I ended up having $x^3-6x^2+5x+24=0$, thanks. Makes sense

Answer (score 4):

This problem relates to elementary symmetric polynomials and the Fundamental Theorem of Elementary Symmetric Polynomials.

Note that $a$, $b$ and $c$ are roots of $x^3-\frac{7}{9}x+\frac{6}{9}=0$. So we can deduce that

$$\sigma_1=abc=-\frac{6}{9}$$
$$\sigma_2=ab+ac+bc=-\frac{7}{9}$$
$$\sigma_3=a+b+c=0$$

Then, an equation with roots $3a+2,3b+2$ and $3c+2$ will have the form:
$$(x-(3a+2))(x-(3b+2))(x-(3c+2))=0$$

Expanding the above equation will give us:

$$x^3-(3a+2+3b+2+3c+2)x^2+[(3a+2)(3b+2)+(3a+2)(3c+2)+(3b+2)(3c+2)]x-(3a+2)(3b+2)(3c+2)=0$$

Note that the coefficients of $x^0,x$ and $x^2$ in the above equation are all symmetric. Hence you should be able to use the Fundamental Theorem to obtain the coefficients of the above equation and solve the question.

Remarks: My solution isn’t wrong but as mentioned by @PierreCarre, it is a rather complicated method. To see a simpler solution, look at David Quinn’s solution.

Comment: Let me try once

Comment: You're killing a fly with a canon...

Comment: @PierreCarre Hahahaha didnt think of substituting y=3x+2 as suggested by David Quinn's solution